# Inserting object to mongodb using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Iam trying to insert object to mongodb and I didnt find how. 
In my way the object inserted gets the id 00000

Here is my code:

```
public static async Task InsertData<T>(string collection_name, object insertData) 
DB mongoConnection = new DBconnection();

var collection = mongoConnection._database.GetCollection<object>(collection_name);

await collection.InsertOneAsync(insertData)
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is the sample model of `insertData`?

MongoDB should generate id automatically if you mark Id field in your models with attributes:

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: I edit the model iam inserting to what you wrote and now the id is null. This is what it was before:  [BsonId] [BsonElement("Identify")] public ObjectId _id {get; set;}

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594270/mongodb-automatically-generated-ids-are-zeroes @marcinax seems like driver bug